# How to record screen in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, screen-recording

### Are there any extensions to record the screen in VSCode

Often developers record screen to share it to peers or to share content.

There are screen recorders like Quick Time on Mac and OBS Studio on windows.
But generally Screen recordings on VS Code are short. It would be easy to record screen if there are any extensions handy in the **Status Bar of VSCode**

Comment: There is a free Windows store app that I use that is brilliant...cheers: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/free-screen-recorder/9p7bfxjtbtzz

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what you need. It has `gif` support as well as `mp4`. Timer and much more.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=arcsine.chronicler

Answer (score 3):

**win + G** Windows 10 a screen recorder is available in the OS. But it will work only if you have a graphic card.

---

For Mac-OS in visual studio code.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wk-j.screen-recorder
[image]
[image]

## Screen Recorder

> Record Visual Studio Code Screen

## Install

> Command + P
>
> Type: ext install screen-recorder

## Support

> [x] macOS
>
> [ ] Windows
>
> [ ] Linux

## Usage

> Click Record Screen / Stop Recording in Status Bar.

Comment: Who doesn't have a GPU tho? Even if it's on your CPU, that should work.

Answer (score 3):

If you are working on Windows 10 a screen recorder is embedded in the OS. You can find it by pressing `Win + G`.

Comment: Note: This feature is only available if you have a graphic card in your PC

Comment: ... and seems like it doesn't record the menu-bars submenus :/

Comment: @HaaLeo who doesn't tho? Even if it's on your CPU, that should work well.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found anything better than [Chronicler](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=arcsine.chronicler&ssr=false#overview) till now. By setting `animatedGif?` to `true` in the `settings.json` file, the output recording will automatically be converted to gif. I used it on Windows work machine and use **screen-recorder** on Linux :)

1. Open settings.json file (Right click on Chronicler once it is installed -> Configure Extension Settings -> Edit in settings.json)
2. Add this line, "chronicler.recording-defaults.animatedGif": true
3. Save it

From now on, your recordings will be converted to gif.

PS: It is only able to capture a part of the screen and not the whole screen, still trying to figure out if i am missing something.